# Given fields $F\subset K \subset E$ with $E/F$ normal, prove that $E/K$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> If $F\subset K \subset E$, with $E/F$ normal, prove that $E/K$ is normal.

I know that  $F\subset K \subset E$ can imply if $E/F$ is algebraic then $E/K$ is algebraic. But how the $ 2 $-nd condition of the definition of the normal extention works, i.e. if the irreducible polynomial $p\in K[x]-F[x]$ has a zero in $E$,why the other zero must be in $E$?

Comment: If $E$ is the splitting field of a family of $F$-polynomials, then since $F$-polynomials are also $K$-polynomials $E$ must also be the splitting field of a family of $K$-polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing your added question in your OP:

Suppose we have an *irreducible* $\;p(x)\in K[x]\;$ which has a root $\,\alpha\in E\;$ . Since $\;E/F\;$ is algebraic there exists an irreducible $\,f(x)\in F[x]\,$ s.t. $\;f(\alpha)=0\;$ . But clearly **also** $\,f(x)\in K[x]\;$ , so we have

$$p(x)\mid f(x)\;\;\text{in}\;\;K[x]\implies\;\exists\,g(x)\in K[x]\;\;s.t.\,\,f(x)=p(x)g(x)$$

Thus, any root of $\,p(x)\;$ is also a root of $\,f(x)\,$ , and since all the roots of this last polynomial are in $\,E\,$ (why?! This is the magical step) we get all the roots of $\,p(x)\;$ are in $\;E\implies E/K\;$ is normal.